# If statement not seeing file

Tags: file, perl, if-statement

I am having an issue with the `if` statement in Perl.

I am not able to get the `if` statement to see the file using `-e`. I basically have files with extension `.new` and `.old`.

```perl
my $dir      = "/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates";
my @oldfiles = glob "$dir/*.new";
my $oldfile;

print "checking for new templates\n";

foreach $oldfile ( @oldfiles ) {

    print "$oldfile\n";

    if ( $oldfile =~ /(\S+)\.new/ ) {

        my $newfile = $1;
        print "$newfile\n";

        if ( -e $newfile ) {
            print "file exist\n";
        }
        else {
            print "file does not exist\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Here is my output:

```
checking for new templates
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/a.txt.new
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/a.txt
file does not exist
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/b.txt.new
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/b.txt
file does not exist
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/m.txt.new
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/m.txt
file does not exist
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/n.txt.new
/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates/n.txt
file does not exist
```

Comment: What do you mean `sees the file`? What is your expectation about the output of your script?

Comment: Do those files actually exist?

Comment: I executed your test after touching 3 files `a.txt.new`, `a.txt`, and `b.txt.new`. The code responded by correctly saying `a.txt` existed but `b.txt` did not. I would think that if you `ls /Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates` before you execute your perl script, then you'll see that the files actually do *not* exist, as @Shawn posits.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code either.

Comment: Tip: you can do `foreach my $var (@ary) { ... }` -- declare the loop variable inside the `foreach` statement itself (same goes for `while` loop).  That way it's scoped to the loop (doesn't exist outside), and the code is much cleaner.  Unless, of course, you _need it_ after the loop but that would be a tricky design.

Comment: @zdim: *"same goes for while loop"* But `while` loops have no loop variable!

Comment: @Borodin Good point. Clearly I was referring to `while (my $e = pop @ary) { say $e }` ... but that's not a "_loop variable_" and I don't know an obvious name for it

Comment: @zdim: Well that's just a local declaration, and has nothing to do with it being in a loop.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, and that was my point, that one can declare a variable inside the loop condition, much like one can in the `foreach` statement (I see often that people don't realize this), which is thus local to the loop.  But I don't know how to refer to it with a single word/phrase (since as you say it indeed isn't a "_loop variable_")

Comment: Ok, so it seems I just didnt understand my code well enough. I was missing the `.txt` files to complate my test run. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

> I basically have files with extension `.new` and `.old`

So you have `a.txt.new` and `a.txt.old` but no `a.txt`, and the message `file does not exist` seems to be correct

You seem to be confused over your variables: you have all the `*.txt.new` file names in an array called `@oldfiles` while `$newfile` has no `.new` or `.old` suffix at all. Did you perhaps mean something more like this?

```
my $dir      = "/Users/henry/Desktop/perltest/templates";
my @oldfiles = glob "$dir/*.old";

print "Checking for new templates\n\n";

for my $oldfile ( @oldfiles ) {

    print "Old file \"$oldfile\"\n";

    my $newfile = $oldfile;
    $newfile =~ s/\.old$/.new/;

    print "New file \"$newfile\" ";

    if ( -e $newfile ) {
        print "exists\n";
    }
    else {
        print "doesn't exist\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It seemed to me that their "oldfile" has `.new` and a new file just doesn't.  @Tags: the naming is really confusing, I had to read back and forth and am still not sure -- can you clarify? (Best by editing the question and at least adding a comment.)

Comment: @zdim: The OP does say *"I basically have files with extension `.new` and `.old`"*

Comment: Ah, I see. Forgot about it with tracing through code. Hopefully they clarify/confirm. Somehow these names manage to really confuse it.

Comment: I do have `.txt` files but I was missing them. I just didn't understand the process well enough.

Comment: And yes the variables are confusing.

Comment: @Tags: So you *do* have `a.txt` as well as `a.txt.new` and `a.txt.old` but your code is still reporting that files don't exist when they do?

Comment: @Tags: So change the variable names!

Comment: I was missing the `a.txt` file. It has always worked. Im going to change the code up. Its confusing to read and I dont like the nested if statements.